# Linear transformation with matrices in base

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, transformation

Consider the vector space of real $2 x 2$ matrices and take as base $\{{E_{11},E_{12},E_{21},E_{22}}\}$. Where $E_{ij}$ represents the matrix with a $1$ in the $i$-th row and $j$-th column and the remaining space filled with zeros.

Consider in this space the linear transformation of real  $2 x 2$ matrices $T : \Bbb R^{2x2} \to \Bbb R^{2x2}$ that $A \to A^T$.

Determine the matrix of this linear transformation against given base.

I'm used to doing transformations with vectors in the base but not with matrices in the base. How do I approach this problem?

Comment: Consider using `\to` rather than `->`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remember that, according to our choice of base, the coordinate vector corresponding to $a E_{11} + bE_{12} + cE_{21} + dE_{22}$ is
$$
\pmatrix{a\\b\\c\\d}
$$
Now, we calculate $T(v)$ for each $v$ in our base.  The $i$th column is the $i$th coordinate vector of $T(v)$.

For example: the second basis element is $E_{12}$, and $T(E_{12}) = E_{21}$, which is represented by the coordinate vector 
$$
\pmatrix{0\\0\\1\\0}
$$
So, this vector is the *second* column of our transformation matrix.

All together, we end up with
$$
M = \pmatrix{
1&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1
}
$$

Comment: I don't understand how you get the coordinate vector of $E_{21}$

Comment: Note that $E_{21} = 0E_{11} + 0E_{12} + 1E_{21} + 0E_{22}$.  Then, apply the first formula.

Comment: Ok, I understand it, thank you.